# Beautiful Soup deeper parse in web site

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to get btc price in this web site.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://koinim.com"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

g_data = soup.find_all(attrs={"nav-BTC-price"})

print(g_data)
```

the result is :

```
[<strong class="nav-BTC-price">10002.99</strong>]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

ı just wanna take the BTC price (10002.99).

ty

Comment: `g_data[0].text` -> `'10002.99'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *text* attribute:

```
[g.text for g in g_data]
# ['10049.00']
```

Comment: ty so much it worked. Can't I get price in one line? ı tried 

g_data = soup.find_all(attrs={"div": "nav-BTC-price"}) - this doesn't work

Comment: If there is only one price, you can use the `find` method, then you can get it in one line `soup.find(attrs={"nav-BTC-price"}).text`